# how to get all lines in list and get something search from this list

Tags: python

```
import csv
f = open("savewl_ssj500k22_Minfreq1-lowercaseWords_1.csv", "r")
csvF = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
s = 0
sez = []
sezB = []
for q in f:
    s = s + 1
    if s > 3:
        l = q.split(",")
        x = l[1]
        y = l[0]
        sezB.append(y)
        sezB.append(int(x))
        sez.append(sezB)
print(sez)

f.close()
```

How to get it work to get all rows from `.csv` in list or `sez` saved

from this code I get: `MemoryError`

in file is 77214 lines of something like this : `je,17031`

Comment: how big is your file?

Comment: 938 KB (960.631 B)

Comment: can you show us the exception, i.e. traces?

Comment: csvF is never used btw.

Comment: its for my school work i must use .csv

Answer (score 1):

Every loop you are appending `sezB` which is growing by itself.
so you are apparently grows by O(number of lines ^2).

This is something like this pattern (just for the explanation):

```
[[1,2], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5,6], .....]
```

I guess you wanted to reset `sezB` to `[]` every loop.

Comment: problem is now thet its squeezd text in to 13883 lines

Comment: I am nor sure what is expected output. Suggest you give sample inputs and expected output in your original question.

Comment: i need to get all of lines in a list or array the frst is string and 2. is int

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to

```
import csv

s = 0
sez = []
sezB = []

with open("savewl_ssj500k22_Minfreq1-lowercaseWords_1.csv", "r") as f:
    csvF = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for q in f:
        s += 1
        if s > 3:
            l = q.split(",")
            x, y = l[:2]
            sezB.extend([x, int(y)])
            sez.append(sezB)
print(sez)
```

As you can see, you constantly add 2 more element to the `sezB` list, which is not that much, but you also keep adding the resulting `sezB` list to the `sez` list.

So since the file has `77214` lines, **`sez` will need to hold about 6 trillion *(`5962079010`)* strings**, which is *way* too many to be stored into memory...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/98pet/OneDrive/Desktop/python/naloga1,prava.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(sez)
MemoryError

Comment: @JanPetrović Since the file has 77214 lines, sez will need to hold about 6 trillion (5962079010) strings, which is way too many to be stored into memory.

Comment: i know it was my mistake for thet aut it need to hold 77214 strings and 77214 int variables sou its not 6 trillion